# How to use special character (-) in appsync enum?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I would like to represent locale information using appsync Type enum. However, there are some special inside locale information. e.g. the `-` in `en-US`, `en-UK`.

If it is possible, I want to retain the format of the locale string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GraphQL specification [does not allow](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Names) `-` in names. So the answer is simply that it is not possible.

What you could do is create an object type that wraps the enum and the locale string:

```
enum LocaleIdentifier {
  EN_US
  EN_UK
  # ...
}

type Locale {
  id: LocaleIdentifier
  str: String
}
```

This would allow you to use the string in the frontend every time you get a Locale but reference the locale with an enum type. I am not sure if there is a lot of value in that instead of simply using the string directly.

Comment: From my understanding, the value of using enums is to restrict the input. And enum resolvers should work here, not? https://blog.logrocket.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-graphql-enums/ (I'm myself fairly new to Graphql, was just looking into the very same question, and found this blog post)

Comment: The question was if it is possible to create a GraphQL enum `en-EN` and the answer is no. You can of course remap your enum value from, for example `en-En` to the string `"en-EN"`. But not every GraphQL implementation supports that.